# How to make hardlinks across two NFS shares?

Tags: nfs, hard-link, nfsv4

Is there a way to make hard-links, from the client side, across two or more NFS mounts, if the shared NFS directories are hosted on a single backing filesystem? (Such that the server would have no problem with the inodes and hard-links if logged in locally or over ssh.)

I have a server providing multiple directories as NFSv4 shares. All of the shared directories are on one [ext4] file system. They are shared separately so the clients can mount them separately.

Within the directory tree of mounted share A or B individually, I can make a hard link of `bar.file`. But if I attempt to `ln` or `cp -l` between mount A and B I get an `Invalid cross-device link` error. Is there a way around this other than directly logging into the server?

I was thinking maybe a short script that reads the inode of the source and manually creates a file entry with the same inode in the destination directory, but that seems kind of hacky and I would need to research the needed components.

Or maybe some sort of union-mount solution?

Assume I have both regular user and root access to both systems.

Comment: You can't manually create a file entry to an arbitrary inode using the standard APIs. (That would allow accessing files contained in directories you have no access to.)

Comment: @ilkkachu root is always allowed access to all directories, and I can log into either system as root.

Comment: Why do you think that having the same inode on two different mounts would link the files in any way? It is quite common for two local file systems to have inodes in common and the files are not in any way related.

Comment: @doneal24 That isn't related to this issue. As stated in the question the NFS shares are all on one file system.

Comment: You stated your using two or more NFS mounts. How is the client to know that /mnt/a is on the same NAS file system as /mnt/b? At the minimum, if you update /mnt/a/foo and then read /mnt/b/foo you will have caching issues. So if you log into the NAS and make the hard link there you might get closer to what you want but you will still have problems on the clients.

Comment: @MaxPower *root is always allowed access to all directories*  [Nope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control)

Comment: @MaxPower, err, yes, root can access all directories, so you could of course log in to the server and create whatever links you like there. Though of course you could do that as a regular user anyway, provided the access rights allow for that, and anyway you asked for ways to do it without logging in to the server...

Comment: @AndrewHenle root can be limited without going through RBAC. A simple addition of `root_squash` to the exports file is sufficient.

Comment: @MaxPower, But you can't make links to arbitrary inodes even as root, you can just link to an existing file. _Using the standard APIs_ that is, I'm not sure if the NFS protocol allows that. If it does, you could do that, but then it's not the access to those directories that's the critical step, but the nonstandard protocol access...

Comment: @ilkkachu Check out my comment and that of Andrews. root can be prevented from accessing directories.

Comment: @doneal24, I did, and frankly, it doesn't seem relevant to the point I'm trying to make here. If you have information on what the NFS protocol allows, though, I'll be happy to hear about that.

Comment: @doneal24, also, if they're planning on doing some shenanigans on purpose, they can likely just set any RBAC controls the way they like on the client side, and present any faked identities to the server. `root_squash` works for protecting directories that are only writable by root, but it doesn't stop the client side root from just switching UIDs and accessing someone's home directory that way.

Comment: @ilkkachu I only meant that restricting access would not be a solid reason for the feature to be excluded from the APIs. But as you indicated it only matters that it is not a regular API, the why it is not isn't the core issue.

Answer (score 2):

#### General observation

> They are shared separately so the clients can mount them separately.

This reasoning makes little sense. If the parent directory was shared, clients could mount subdirectories separately *anyway*. One may want to share directories separately if there is (or if there may appear) something in the parent directory one does not want to share. This can be a valid reason, there may be other reasons. But…

Giving ability to mount separately is not a valid reason to share separately. NFSv4 gives the ability to clients regardless. `/etc/exports` on the server is an *access control list* rather than a list of *separate* shares clients must stick to. When using `mount` on a client, you are *not limited* to exact paths that are in `/etc/exports` on the server. As a client you can mount `/` of the server and still get access to all shares (and nothing more); or you can mount any subdirectory you are allowed to access.

Try mounting `/` of the server. Try mounting some (((…)sub-)sub-)subdirectory of some share. My point is you can.

---

#### Solution

`Invalid cross-device link` you got was because locally on the NFS client the paths you used were formally on separate "devices". The solution is to mount a hierarchy (directory tree) that includes all relevant shares, so it appears locally under one mountpoint (i.e. as a single "device").

On your NFS client mount the root directory (`/`) of the server; or the remote moutpoint of the remote filesystem in question; or some other common parent directory of the shares. A remote path you mount does not have to be explicitly exported on the server. Example:

```
sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.99.7:/remote/mountpoint /local/mountpoint
```

Under your local mounpoint you will see the content of the chosen remote directory limited to exported shares. E.g. if remote directories `/remote/mountpoint/foo/A` and `/remote/mountpoint/bar/baz/B` are exported and nothing in `/remote/mountpoint/qux` is exported (and even if neither `/` nor `/remote/mountpoint` is exported) then locally in `/local/mountpoint` you will see `foo/` and `bar/`, but not `qux/`. You will be able to reach `foo/A/` and `bar/baz/B/`.

Now, by working strictly under `/local/mountpoint`, you can `ln` locally between the directories `A` and `B` and if they are indeed on the same filesystem on the server and if you are permitted to write then the operation will succeed.

Comment: I guess the purpose is to handle cases where there are no common parent, like in `mount address:/remote/A /mntA; mount address:/remote/B /mntB; ln /mntA/file /mntB/file`... but of course, if there is a common parent, the solution is easy.

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer In your example `/remote` is the common parent; when in doubt use `/`: `mount address:/ /local/mountpoint && ln /local/mountpoint/remote/A/file /local/mountpoint/remote/B/file`.

Comment: If `/remote/A` and `/remote/B` are exported, but not `/remote` (nor `/` for obvious security reason), your proposition can't work. But sure, if `/remote` contains many exported directories, a new organisation could make safe to put these directories in a single one and export this directory. (Assuming the OP has an access to the server).

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer My proposal can work. Try to mount `/` of some NFS server and you will be surprised.

Comment: NFS is weird. I just wonder, does that depend on which NFS version one uses? On a quick look, I seem to get the impression the exports are separate in NFSv3, but parts of a single tree (as you describe above) in NFSv4.

Comment: It is a physically viable workaround. But isn't a full solution due to two issues: A is that I don't want to expose everything in the server parent directory to every client. And B even if I reorganized the whole server to solve A, it would add an extra layer to the client directory tree. B is inconvenient both because the shared directories are traversed frequently, and it breaks a handful of symbolic links and some other scripted stuff on the clients. (Although I could make a hidden mount point and add even more symbolic links into it. Workable but messy.)

Comment: Also reorganizing the server is easier said than done for the shares in question. It uses a proprietary UI and flavor of Linux which really likes its stock directory tree.

Answer (score 1):

A usual implementation of most file systems, including a NFS share, defines - like in an oriented object language - a set of operations (open, read...) you can do INSIDE the mounted filesystem. The NFS client implementation has no way to deal with operation with other filesystems. (From the client point of view, there are 2 file systems).

It may be theorically possible to have a dedicated client which mounts 2 NFS filesystems (sending NFS info), get 2 filehandles, then use them to link 2 files (sending NFS info too). But if it is not provided by your OS, it would be a lot of pain without a 100% chance of success. It could depend of the server implementation.