# NFS: mounting root mounts all file systems mounted under it

Tags: nfs

I was reading about NFS [here](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-and-configure-an-nfs-server-on-ubuntu-20-04/).
I can't understand the use of mentioning crossmnt with fsid=0.

I observed something weird.
Server's /etc/exports had the following 3 lines

```
/srv/nfs4 192.168.1.0/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,fsid=0)
/srv/nfs4/test_share 192.168.1.0/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
/srv/nfs4/test_share_lv2 192.168.1.0/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

here /srv/nfs4/test_share and /srv/nfs4/test_share_lv2 are two different LVM LVs with ext4 FS.

I mounted only /srv/nfs4 in my client using

```
sudo mount -t nfs -o vers=4 192.168.1.100:/ /media/nfs_test/
```

After this, I can access both the LVs from the NFS client under the paths /media/nfs_test/test_share*. This happens irrespective of using crossmnt in fsid=0. This does not seem to conform to what is mentioned under crossmnt in the [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/5/exports).

Why does mounting / mount all the subdir file system exported under it? This happens irrespective of mentioning crossmnt in NFS root in the server. Please help me understand this.

Comment: Compare [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/742187/108618). Treat `/etc/exports` as an access control list. I guess [it depends on the version of NFS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/742175/108618#comment1410674_742187) though.